# Controlar error con un QInputDialog

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

¿Como puedo capturar cuando el usuario no introduce datos y pulsa ok o pulsa cancelar en un QInputDialog?
Solo encuentro ayuda para usar el QInputDialog cuando el usuario pulsa ok pero nada cuando pulsa cancelar o no escribe nada en el y pulsa ok.

```
text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Elegir hoja", "Elige la hoja a cargar:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Elegir hoja", "Elige la hoja a cargar:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")

```
    while True:

            if okPressed and text != '':
                   print(text)
                   
            else:
                print('Cancelado')
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Atención", "No has escrito nada!")
                return False
            break
```

Comment: Después de varias, respondo yo mismo. Esto a mi me ha funcionado.